# Jquery Ajax success function not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Ajax success function not working. my php page return the value but not coming into success function. I am using the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yealysearch').click(function(){
        var year=$('#sel_year').val();
        $('#yearlydata').val('');
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"get_yearlyreport.php",
            data:{year},
            cache: false,
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert('sdfsdfsdf');
            },
            error: function(ts) { alert(1) }
        }); 
    });     
})
```

Thanks

Comment: data:{year: year},

Comment: `data: {year}` is valid in ES6.

Comment: Do you return output from php?

Comment: is id#yealysearch correctly?

Comment: Your `alert()` inside `success` callback is never fired?

Comment: *How* have you confirmed that your "php page return the value"?    Do you get the error alert?  What's the definition of your php page?  Should it be a 'GET' instead of 'POST'?  (especially as it's called "get_yearlyreport")

Comment: share the php code. It will be easier to check

Answer (score 0):

```
data:{year},
```

change to :

```
data:{year : year},
```

Comment: Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how or why they resolve the issue in the question. You should update your answer to explain what this code does and why it fixes the issue.